# Shiny App: Global data structure based on reactive input

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, selectinput

I am trying to render some output plots in a Shiny app but need input values to change a "global" data structure (aka I need the data to be accessible to render multiple plots).

This is a simplified version of my app

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
     selectInput("target_state", NULL, choices=setNames(tolower(state.abb), state.name), selected='pa')
   ),
   fluidRow(
     column(plotOutput("plot1", height="220px")),
     column(plotOutput("plot1", height="220px"))
)

server <- function(input,output) {

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({## code to generate plot here})
output$plot2 <- renderPlot({## code to generate another plot here})
}
```

I want to load specific data sets based on the input of `target_state`. I have tried the following:

```
data_in <- reactive({
   in_file <- read.csv(paste0("datafile.",input$target_state,".csv")
   as.data.frame(in_file)
})
```

Then tried referencing this as both a data structure (as `data_in`) and as a function (`data_in()')
This loads fine initially, but the plots do not change when I select different input values. And I am trying to avoid reloading the data everytime I need it. How can I go about dynamically loading a "global" dataset in my Shiny app?

Comment: Your logic appears correct, but you haven’t provided a reproducible example, so I can’t spit the error in your code.  (I presume ono of the  `plotOutput(“plot1”`s is a typo…)